# Can we add a creation_date to the /sites method?

Tags: discussion, date

I think we really need a way to determine when one of the new sites went live so that they can be ordered by date.

Something like:

```
{
    "name": "Gaming Meta",
    "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/gamingmeta/logo.png",
    "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.gaming.stackexchange.com",
    "site_url": "http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com",
    "description": "Q&A about the Gaming site",
    "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchymeta/apple-touch-icon.png",
    "state": "linked_meta",
    "creation_date": 1279825996,
    "styling": {
        "link_color": "#3D3D3D",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#666666",
        "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
}
```

*Notice the `creation_date` item.*

Answer (score 2):

A work around for this would be to check the `creation_date` of `/users/1`.

Comment: Ah. Very good idea!

Comment: + or `/users/-1`

Comment: @geo - of course it does. http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/users/-1

Comment: @code: My bad. Entered the wrong URL.